# SSRS Alternating row color issues when some rows are not visible

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report where I have a customerID group, and no detail group.  The dataset that I have going to the report will have each customer, as well as numerous columns of information for that customer.  I have created a bunch of rows, that are labeled appropriately, and displays valid data associated with it (ex. **Age:** 34, **Sex:** Male).  I also have some rows where the data coming back may be blank or NULL.  These rows I choose to hide the visibility for.  I am unsure how to handle the alternating background color, because there's always going to be some rows that are not visible, but you can't predict which ones they will be.  If I had the data unpivoted in the dataset, I could just eliminate the rows that would not be visible, and just display the rows with a detail grouping and do the RowNumber Mod solution.  I was hoping there's an easy way to do this the way that I currently have it set up though.  Is there a way to check the background color of the previous visible row? Set a report variable to the color of what the next visible row should be?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/104711/How-to-set-an-alternate-row-color-in-SSRS) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011213/ssrs-alternating-row-colour-within-groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Alternating Row Color **code** instead of the ROWNUMBER.

```
Private bOddRow As Boolean
'*************************************************************************
' -- Display green-bar type color banding in detail rows
' -- Call from BackGroundColor property of all detail row textboxes
' -- Set Toggle True for first item, False for others.
'*************************************************************************
Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, _
         ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean) As String
    If Toggle Then bOddRow = Not bOddRow
    If bOddRow Then
        Return OddColor
    Else
        Return EvenColor
    End If
End Function
```

Set the BackgroundColor of your row cells with

```
=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)
```

[Add alternating row color to SQL Server Reporting services report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report)

Comment: This worked.  I had seen this solution while doing my research, but never considered it actually working because I figured that even though a row was set to not visible, it would still alter the BackgroundColor property for that row, therefore, would have some instances of back to back white rows or back to back gainsboro rows.  Also, had to make sure to set the Toggle trigger to False on all columns after the first for each row.  Thanks for suggesting I try this.  I knew there had to be an easy way!

Comment: Yes, but how do you compute true and false then ? Setting the color is not the problem...

Comment: @StefanSteiger - You set the first column to TRUE and the others are FALSE. This changes the `bOddRow` variable when it renders the next row.